# Pandas apply convolve by group of rows

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, convolution

I have a pandas dataframe like below :

```
   profile_index  point_index         z              x             y
0              0            1 -0.885429  297903.323027  6.669492e+06
1              0            2 -0.820151  297904.117752  6.669492e+06
2              0            3 -0.729671  297904.912476  6.669491e+06
3              0            4 -0.649332  297905.707201  6.669490e+06
4              1            1 -0.692186  297906.501926  6.669490e+06
5              1            2 -0.885429  297903.323027  6.669492e+06
6              1            3 -0.820151  297904.117752  6.669492e+06
3              1            4 -0.649332  297905.707201  6.669490e+06
```

I want to create a new "z_gauss" column by applying a convolution (numpy.convolve) with a gaussian filter on vectors (column z) corresponding to a group of rows in my dataframe with the same "profile_index".

I've tried to do something like

`data["z_gauss"] = data.groupby('profile_index').apply(lambda x: np.convolve(x, gaussian, 'same'))`

where `gaussian` is my gaussian filter (vector). But I get some errors like `ValueError: object too deep for desired array`

Do you have any advices/hints on how to proceed ? Should I split my dataframe into different ones ?

Comment: `data.groupby('profile_index')['x'].apply(lambda x: np.convolve(x, gaussian, 'same'))`?

Comment: Thx, this looks like quite an improvement, but it returns a vector per row that has the size of the group whereas i need a single value per row. Any way to transpose back the vectors along the rows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use a transform instead of an apply. This will avoid inserting a vector wth the size of the group per row:

```
data["z_gauss"] = (data.groupby('profile_index')['z']
                   .transform(lambda x: np.convolve(x, gaussian, 'same')))
```

Comment: Indeed, I changed the method from apply to transform and I get what I expected, thank you ! I need to read more documention about the difference between the two methods though because I don't really understand this behaviour. Btw, you should update your code snippet because it still mention the apply method.

Comment: No prob. Updated :)

Comment: I don't know if this is the right place to ask (maybe I should start a new thread), but : is it possible to apply this transformation on a slice (because my filter doesn't apply on boundaries) of the Series, or should I change values back once the transformation is done ?